# Will Apple ID password also be changed automatically?

Tags: yahoo-mail, apple-id

There is an apple id testmail@yahoo.com and a MacBook has been signed in with testmail@yahoo.com.

Recently yahoo account (testmail@yahoo.com) password has been changed.
Please let me know, by default, will Apple ID password also be changed automatically?

As per my knowledge, it will not be changed.

Regards
TekQ

Answer (score 5):

No.

Apple have absolutely no clue what your email password is. It has nothing to do with iCloud, or your Mac.
You are simply using that email as your AppleID. An AppleID doesn't even actually **have** to be an email address at all, so long as there is a real email address associated with the ID, so you can be contacted/use 2FA etc.

Comment: Do you mean, if yahoo account (testmail@yahoo.com) password has been changed, Apple ID (testmail@yahoo.com) password will not be changed automatically and by default?

Comment: No it will not.  My Apple ID is gmail and the passwords are different and I change them separately.  Just as this answer says.

Comment: Your AppleID is in no way connected to your email account - it's simply a means to identify you. That would even apply if your email was someone@icloud.com